# strncpy vs direct assignment seg fault

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior, strcpy

The following code below runs without a seg fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void)
{   
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
    head->data = "test";
    printf("data: %s\n", head->data);

    return 0;
}
```

when I switch the code to so

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void)
{   
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
    strncpy(head->data, "test", 512);
    printf("data: %s\n", head->data);

    return 0;
}
```

I receive a seg fault and am forced to switch my node property data to be of type char data[512]. Why is this required? I thought arrays are inherently pointers, so this behavior is not making sense to me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node {
    char data[512];
    struct node *next;
};

int main(void)
{   
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    
    strncpy(head->data, "test", 512);
    printf("data: %s\n", head->data);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected that both pointers and arrays could be assigned string values in the same way.

Comment: `I thought arrays are inherently pointers` They are not.

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for the string in version 2

Comment: Use `strdup` rather than `strncpy`

Comment: `strncpy(head->data, "test", 512);` Why `512`? There isn't any memory allocation.

Comment: Think about the difference between `p = &v;` vs `*p = v;`

Comment: *I thought arrays are inherently pointers*  No.  Pointers are **variables** that **hold an address** - and the address in a pointer may or may not be valid.  Arrays are **chunks of memory** that **have an address**.  Your home has an address, and if someone puts that address on a letter, your post office will deliver it to you.  If someone puts "North Pole" as the address, Santa isn't going to get it...

Answer (score 3):

In this statement

```
head->data = "test";
```

the string literal having the array type `char[5]` is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element and this pointer is assigned to the pointer `head->data`.

In this statement

```
strncpy(head->data, "test", 512);
```

you are using an uninitialized pointer `head->data` and trying to copy the whole string literal to the memory pointed to by that pointer with an indeterminate value. That invokes undefined behavior.

> I thought arrays are inherently pointers, so this behavior is not
> making sense to me.

Arrays are not pointers. They can be implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements in most situations but this does not mean that arrays are pointers.

Consider the simple demonstration program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    char data[512];
    char *p = data;

    printf( "sizeof( data ) = %zu\n", sizeof( data ) );
    printf( "sizeof( p ) = %zu\n", sizeof( p ) );
}
```

Its output might look like

```
sizeof( data ) = 512
sizeof( p ) = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second snippet (the one that crashes), you allocate memory for the `node` struct, which includes the pointer `data`. However, this pointer is never initialized, and it points to some arbitrary memory address (or just `NULL`), meaning that writing to it is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and indeed likely to just segfault.

For it to point to a valid memory address, you'll have to explicitly allocate it:

```c
struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
head->data = malloc(sizeof(char) * 512 /* or some other size, of course */);
```

Comment: Thank you, does this method of initialization provide any benefits rather than char data[512] in the struct? I suppose dynamic size possible on the struct?

Comment: @cquestions indeed, you can choose a more informed size, and even have different sizes for different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this required? I thought arrays are inherently pointers, so this behavior is not making sense to me.

Pointers are just pointers and the only memory they occupy is the memory required to store an address. If you want a pointer to point at dynamically allocated memory, you need to allocate it yourself.

Example:

```c
struct node {
    char *data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *create_node(const char *str) {
    struct node *nn = malloc(sizeof *nn);
    if(nn) {
        nn->data = strdup(str); // allocate strlen(str)+1 bytes and copy the string
        if(nn->data) {          // strdup was successful
            nn->next = NULL;
        } else {                // strdup failed
            free(nn);
            nn = NULL;
        }
    }
    return nn;
}

void destroy_node(struct node *n) {
    free(n->data);
    free(n);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought arrays are inherently pointers

**Array Vs pointer:**

An array might decay to a pointer in expressions and function parameters, and array accesses might be rewritten by the compiler as pointer accesses, but they are not interchangeable. An array name is an address, and a pointer is the address of an address.

---

> Why is this required?

Declaring a pointer only allocates memory for the pointer.

You can initialise a pointer in two ways:

- Either with a string literal:

  ```
  ptr = "abcd";
  ```

  Originally, `ptr` was
  indeterminate. But this changes
  what it was pointing to such that
  it now points to a string literal.
  The compiler will store the
  address of the first element of
  the string literal in `ptr`.

  If you were to do the same with an
  array:

  ```
  char s[] = "String";
  ```

  and then try to change its value:

  ```
  s = "String2"; 

  /* error: assignment to expression 
  with array type */
  ```

  It wouldn't compile, because
  arrays, unlike pointers, are not
  modifiable lvalues.
  You can't change its value.
- Or allocate memory for it and then
  write to it.

  ```
  errno = 0;

  ptr = malloc (size);
  if (!ptr) {
      errno = ENOMEM;
      perror ("malloc ()");
      deal with error here...
  }
  ```

  Now you can use `strcpy ()` to
  copy to it.